# I'm trying to create an app using Framework-7 Vuejs. I want to make my user stay logged in even after exiting the app using Firebase

Tags: firebase, vue.js, cordova

I want to add [Firebase's code](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) in my Framework-7 Vue.js app. So that a user can stay logged in even arter exiting the app.

```
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    store.commit(setSignedIn, true)
  } else {
    store.commit(setSignedIn, false)
  }
});
```

I need to add this in my app.js of my project:

```
// Import Vue
import { createApp } from 'vue';

// Import Framework7
import Framework7 from 'framework7/lite-bundle';

// Import Framework7-Vue Plugin
import Framework7Vue, { registerComponents } from 'framework7-vue/bundle';

// Import Framework7 Styles
import 'framework7/framework7-bundle.css';

// Import Icons and App Custom Styles
import '../css/icons.css';
import '../css/app.css';

// Import App Component
import App from '../components/app.vue';
import store from '../pages/store/store';

// Init Framework7-Vue Plugin
Framework7.use(Framework7Vue);

// Init App
const app = createApp(App);

app.use(store)

// Register Framework7 Vue components
registerComponents(app);

// Mount the app
app.mount('#app');
```

Can someone please help me to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using [Vuex Persisted State](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persistedstate) package for such purposes. It is quite simple to add. Try it out.
With `Vuex Persisted State` your Vuex store will be stored in `localStorage` so the user won't be logged out after exiting the app.

Comment: It worked if I refresh the page I don't need to login! Thanks

I only had to add this in my store.js

import createPersistedState from "vuex-persistedstate";

plugins: [createPersistedState()],